# Output the date/time in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I want to output the date time in various places in my script for logging so I am doing this:

```
$b = Get-Date
Write-Output "Backups complete at $b"

# more code here

$c = Get-Date
Write-Output "Backups complete at $c"
```

I am having to use multiple letters of the alphabet to get the most current date/time.

Is there an easier way of doing this or do I have to reestablish the date each time I want to use it again?

Answer (score 54):

Once you assign the current datetime to a variable, you are capturing the date and time at the moment you ran `Get-Date`.

Every time you want a new date and time, you need to run it again. You could avoid using a variable:

```
Write-Output "Backups complete at $(Get-Date)"
```

Comment: ok I tried it without the () and it didn't work. I get it now. Thank you!

Comment: *cough* make dates sortable with year-month-day-hour-minute-second ordering `Write-Output "Backups complete at $(Get-Date -Format u)"` *cough*

Answer (score 11):

Another way to do this is using a format string and since you are using this for logging purpose I would recommend you to write a function because this will allow you to change the format of all log messages in a single place:

```
function Log-Message
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
        [string]$LogMessage
    )

    Write-Output ("{0} - {1}" -f (Get-Date), $LogMessage)
}
```

Now you can simple log using:

```
Log-Message "Starting Backups"
Log-Message "Backups Completed"
```

**Output:**

```
22.07.2016 08:31:15 - Starting Backups
22.07.2016 08:31:15 - Backups Completed
```

Comment: you should use Write-Information instead of Write-Output

Comment: @MovGP0 you should state WHY you think that, not just state it. What are the benefits of doing so?

Answer (score 9):

Here is simple 1 which allow you format date time in your desire format

```
$currentTime = Get-Date -format "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
Write-Host $currentTime " Other log string message "
```

**OUTPUT**

```
17-Aug-2020 10:06:19  other log string message
```

Comment: well `echo $(Get-Date -format "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")` also work. simpler and more powerful :)