# How to speed up PowerShell script to pull Get-EXOMailbox and Get-EXOMailboxStatistics info with formating on 18k mailboxes

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, exchange-online

I'm a beginner PowerShell user and I've written a script to pull specific information about each user's mailbox and archive in my organization, about 18,000 users.  Currently it's taking around 24 hours to run. I know it's not efficiently coded and I'm hoping someone can help me find a better way to code it to bring the run time down?  Please let me know what techniques could be used to help speed this up.

```
Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)] 
    [string]$OutputPath = 'C:\Temp\Users-ArchiveSize.csv'
)

Connect-ExchangeOnline -UserPrincipalName admin@job.com  -ConnectionUri "https://outlook.office365.com/powershell?email=@yourmailaddress"

$result = @()

$Users = Get-Content -Path "C:\Temp\users-Testing.csv"

Measure-Command { foreach($user in $users) {

    $u = Get-EXOMailbox -Identity $user

    If ($u.AutoExpandingArchiveEnabled -eq $true) {
        $autoArchiveEnabled = "True"
    }
    Else {
        $autoArchiveEnabled = "False"
    }

    $displayName = $u.DisplayName
    $primarySmtpAddress = $u.PrimarySmtpAddress

    $data = Get-EXOMailboxStatistics $u.UserPrincipalName -Archive | select TotalItemSize,ItemCount
    $totalSize = $data.TotalItemSize
    $itemCount = $data.ItemCount

    $result += New-Object psobject -Property @{
        'DisplayName' = $displayName;
        'PrimarySMTP' = $primarySmtpAddress;
        'TotalSize' = $totalSize;
        'ItemCount' = $itemCount;
        'AutoExpandEnabled' = $autoArchiveEnabled;
    }
}
}

if ($OutputPath) {
    $result | Export-Csv -Path $OutputPath -NoTypeInformation
}
```

So far I've tried to isolate the queries against the Exchange database into an array separately, hoping it would be faster than pulling and formatting at the same time, then pulled what I needed out of that array to format and export.  I thought it would help but it actually took longer.

I was exploring the start-job with a script block but I wasn't able to get it to work properly.  I don't think I understand the concept enough, the csv export was empty.  I was able to see that it was correctly performing "$u = Get-EXOMailbox -Identity $user" but creating the variable "$displayName = $u.DisplayName" didn't work, that variable as well as the other variables were all empty.

I was researching and thought running the queries in parallel might be another good option but I'm still trying to see if I can figure out how to do that or even if it's possible.

I'm still just a beginner in PS and the methods/concepts are very hard to wrap my head around and just dive into, I don't have a lot of programming experience.  Any help, even just a direction to go in would really help me out!

**Testing:**

I've tried the following code:

```
Param (
   [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
   [string]$OutputPath = 'C:\Temp\Users-ArchiveSize.csv'
)

#  Open a connection
Connect-ExchangeOnline -UserPrincipalName admin@job.com  -ConnectionUri "https://outlook.office365.com/powershell?email=@yourmailaddress"
#  Get a full list of users and then allocate the same number of cells in $Results
$Users = Get-Content -Path "C:\TEMP\EE\ca-users-Testing-10.csv" | Where-Object {$_ -match "@domain.ca"}
$Results = [PSObject[]]::new($Users.Count)


      
         $Users | & {   #  This stage packages each user with an index indicating their storage location in $Results.
            begin {
               $Index = 0
            }
            process {
               [PSCustomObject]@{
                  Index  = $Index
                  User   = $Users[$Index]
                  Result = $null
               }
               $Index++
            }
         } | Foreach-Object -ThrottleLimit 5 -Parallel { #  This stage builds and saves each PSObject per each user, but doing multiple in parallel
            #  Collect need information on the user
            $u = Get-EXOMailbox -Identity $_.User | Select-Object UserPrincipalName,DisplayName,PrimarySMTPAddress
            $data = Get-EXOMailboxStatistics $u.UserPrincipalName -Archive | Select-Object TotalItemSize
            $archiveStatus = Get-EXOMailbox -Identity $u.UserPrincipalName -PropertySets Archive | Select-Object AutoExpandingArchiveEnabled
            #  Build and save the PSObject containing the needed information on the user
            $_.Result = [PSCustomObject]@{
               'DisplayName'       = $u.DisplayName;
               'PrimarySMTP'       = $u.PrimarySmtpAddress;
               'TotalSize'         = $data.TotalItemSize;
               'AutoExpandEnabled' = $archiveStatus.AutoExpandingArchiveEnabled
            }
            #  Make the PSCustomObject available to the next stage
            $_
         } | & {  #  Save each PSObject in its proper location in $Results
            process {
               $Results[$_.Index] = $_.Result
            }
         }
      


#  Write $Results to file in CSV format
if ($OutputPath) {
   $Results | Export-Csv -Path $OutputPath -NoTypeInformation
}
```

I received the following errors:

```
ForEach-Object : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At C:\Users\ce-eveinarsson\Documents\Get_User_Archive_Size_Parallel_v6.ps1:29 char:14
+ ...         } | Foreach-Object -ThrottleLimit 5 -Parallel { #  This stage ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (:) [ForEach-Object], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ForEachObjectCommand


Export-Csv : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null.
At C:\Users\ce-eveinarsson\Documents\Get_User_Archive_Size_Parallel_v6.ps1:53 char:15
+    $Results | Export-Csv -Path $OutputPath -NoTypeInformation
+               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Export-Csv], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ExportCsvCommand
```

From what I can determine, it pulls the information and I can pull values from $u but as soon as the script gets to $_ it doesn't seem to do anything.  The values $*.Index and $*.Result are null, so when it tries to export-csv $Results, it's a null value and produces the above error?

Comment: The remote Exchange call is probably pretty expensive but as an aside: [try avoid using the increase assignment operator (`+=`) to create a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60708579/1701026) as it is inefficiënt.

Comment: Aside from changing `+=` to an assignment to your loop expression: `$result = foreach($user in $users) {...` there is not much room for improvement other than multithreading with `ForEach-Object -Parallel` if pwsh 7+ or threadjobs / runspaces if pwsh 5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've converted your code 2 times now, both resulting in the code below. I've also tested parts of the code, such as adding items to the `$results` array from within the `for` loop, everything looks good. But I don't have your exact situation, so I can't test the full code for errors or problems.  So, I guess you need to give it a try.

If this throws an error, let me know what you experience and maybe we can figure it out.

```
Param (
   [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
   [string]$OutputPath = 'C:\Temp\Users-ArchiveSize.csv'
)

Connect-ExchangeOnline -UserPrincipalName admin@job.com  -ConnectionUri "https://outlook.office365.com/powershell?email=@yourmailaddress"

$Users = Get-Content -Path "C:\Temp\users-Testing.csv"
$result = [PSObject[]]::new($Users.Count)
Measure-Command -Expression {
   & {
      for ($i = 0; $i -lt $result.Count; $i++) {
         $u = Get-EXOMailbox -Identity $Users[$i]
         $data = Get-EXOMailboxStatistics $u.UserPrincipalName -Archive | Select-Object TotalItemSize, ItemCount
         $result[$i] = [PSObject]@{
            DisplayName       = $u.DisplayName
            PrimarySMTP       = $u.PrimarySmtpAddress
            TotalSize         = $data.TotalItemSize
            ItemCount         = $data.ItemCount
            AutoExpandEnabled = $u.AutoExpandingArchiveEnabled -eq $true
         }
      }
   }
}

if ($OutputPath) {
   $result | Export-Csv -Path $OutputPath -NoTypeInformation
}
```

**Some key points:**

1. You already have an array the size you will be needing - `$Users`, so the code builds an array of type `[PSObject]` that is the same size of the array of users.

   - This removes the need for using `$result +=` which is constantly building new arrays and copying the content of the old.
   - It replaces it with `$result[$i] =` which saves the new PSObjects directly into the already existing cells in the array.
2. I had help from Santiago when working on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77780360/4190564), and he warned me about the `Measure-Command` using [Dot Sourcing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-5.1#dot-sourcing-operator-) `.` to execute the script block

   - This, to my surprise, will reduce the performance of some PowerShell commands and operators.
   - His warning was directly related to the [Call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.4#call-operator-) `&`.
   - But I accidently discovered it also badly degrades the performance of `foreach` loops.

     - My version of your code does NOT use the `foreach`, but it does use a `for` loop which may also be subject to the same problem.
   - Santiago's solution was to use the Call operator from within the script block called by `Measure-Command` to call another script block containing the code you want to measure.

     - `Measure-Command`

       - Script block `{`<code>`}`

         - Call operator `&`

           - Another script block `{`<code>`}`

             - Code you want to measure
3. Your code checks if `$u.AutoExpandingArchiveEnabled -eq $true` and in a very indirect way assigned `$true` if `$true` and `$false` if `$false` to AutoExpandEnabled, I've shortened that considerably, and I question if it needs the  `-eq $true` part.

#### Possible Changes to `Get-EXOMailboxStatistics`:

It would be interesting to see what happens if this:

```
$data = Get-EXOMailboxStatistics $u.UserPrincipalName -Archive | Select-Object TotalItemSize, ItemCount
```

Was changed to the following.  This would help `Get-EXOMailboxStatistics` know what is being handed to it.

```
$data = Get-EXOMailboxStatistics -UserPrincipalName $u.UserPrincipalName -Archive | Select-Object TotalItemSize, ItemCount
```

Or, what if it was changed to the following.  I'm not a pipeline expert, but I believe Select-Object is repackaging 2 properties in a new object that has only those 2 properties.  This seems like a waste of processing time and I don't see the value - but maybe I don't understand the need for it.

```
$data = Get-EXOMailboxStatistics $u.UserPrincipalName -Archive
```

#### Parallel Processing:

The following is a possible design for using PowerShell 7's `Foreach-Object -Parallel`:

```
$OutputPath = "$PSScriptRoot\Results.csv"
$Users = 'User1', 'User2', 'User3', 'User4', 'User5', 'User6', 'User7', 'User8', 'User9'
$Results = [PSObject[]]::new($Users.Count)
Measure-Command -Expression {
   & {
      $Users | & {
         begin {
            $Index = 0
         }
         process {
            [PSCustomObject]@{
               Index  = $Index
               User   = $Users[$Index]
               Result = $null
            }
            $Index++
         }
      } | Foreach-Object -ThrottleLimit 5 -Parallel {
         $i = $_.Index
         $User = $_.User
         $_.Result = [PSObject]@{
            User = $User
            Text = "$i=$User"
         }
         $_
      } | & {
         process {
            $Results[$_.Index] = $_.Result
         }
      }
   }
}
$Results | Export-Csv -Path $OutputPath -NoTypeInformation
```

In PowerShell 7.3.9 it produced a file containing the following:

```
"User","Text"
"User1","0=User1"
"User2","1=User2"
"User3","2=User3"
"User4","3=User4"
"User5","4=User5"
"User6","5=User6"
"User7","6=User7"
"User8","7=User8"
"User9","8=User9"
```

#### Possible Missing Disconnect

Looking at [Connect to Exchange Online PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/connect-to-exchange-online-powershell?view=exchange-ps), I noticed it has a section [Step 3: Disconnect when you're finished](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/connect-to-exchange-online-powershell?view=exchange-ps#step-3-disconnect-when-youre-finished).

Should the script end with this line?:

```
Disconnect-ExchangeOnline -Confirm:$false
```

#### Improving Get-EXOMailbox

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-exomailbox?view=exchange-ps) for Get-EXOMailbox, in the [-Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-exomailbox?view=exchange-ps#-identity) section, says:

> For the best performance, we recommend using the following values:
>
> .  User ID or user principal name (UPN)
> .  GUID

The question is this, what is the content of "C:\Temp\users-Testing.csv"?  Is it UPNs? GUIDs? Other?

If it turns out that it is Other, we could save either the UPN or GUID for each Other in a hash table, save the hash table to a file, load the hash table when the script starts, and do the conversion from Other to either UPN or GUID prior to calling `Get-EXOMailbox`, and passing Other to `Get-EXOMailbox` only when it is missing from the hash table.  I'm skeptical of how much of a performance increase this would give, but if we get desperate, it is an option to consider.

#### Conclusion:

*Contents of the conclusion will likely change as I receive feedback from esquared.*

**Barebones Parallel Version:**
This version is probably fairly close to as good as you will get for performance without rewriting it in C#.  The `-ThrottleLimit` still needs to be adjusted to find that fine point between performance and overloading the server with request. All extras related to processing users is removed, and `Measure-Command` is replaced with a function.

**NOTE:** Even though I call this "Barebones", there are 2 parts that probably aren't needed.  The first is  `| Select-Object TotalItemSize, ItemCount`, which the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.4#description) say *"When you select properties, Select-Object returns new objects that have only the specified properties."* And the second is  `-eq $true` at the end of `AutoExpandEnabled = $u.AutoExpandingArchiveEnabled`.  This second can be proven removable by executing `($u.AutoExpandingArchiveEnabled).GetType()` after `$u` is created. If that command returns "Boolean", then it isn't needed.

The first half of the script defines the $OutputPath parameter, defines function Get-ReadableTimeSince, and connects to server.

```
Param (
   [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
   [string]$OutputPath = 'C:\Temp\Users-ArchiveSize.csv'
)
function Get-ReadableTimeSince {
   [CmdletBinding()]
   param (
      [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
      [DateTime]$DateTime
   )
   $TimeSpan = [DateTime]::now - $DateTime
   [string[]]$TimeList =
   @( $TimeSpan.Days, 'day' ),
   @( $TimeSpan.Hours, 'hour' ),
   @( $TimeSpan.Minutes, 'minute' ),
   @( [float]($TimeSpan.Seconds + $TimeSpan.Milliseconds / 1000), 'second' ) |
   & { process {
         if ($_[0] -ne 1 -and $_[0] -ne 1.0) { $_[1] += 's' }
         if (($_[0])) { '{0} {1}' -f $_[0], $_[1] }
      } }
   if ($TimeList.Count -eq 0) { $TimeList += '0 seconds' }
   $LastIndex = $TimeList.Count - 1
   if ($LastIndex -ge 2) { $TimeList[$LastIndex] = 'and ' + $TimeList[$LastIndex]; $TimeList -join ', ' }
   else { $TimeList -join ' and ' }
}
Connect-ExchangeOnline -UserPrincipalName admin@job.com  -ConnectionUri "https://outlook.office365.com/powershell?email=@yourmailaddress"
```

This second part of the script capture the time, does the work and calls Get-ReadableTimeSince with the time afterwards.  The time will show in only those days, hours, minutes, and seconds that have a value. So it might say something like "5 hours and 23.173 seconds" if its been 0 minutes since the top of the hour.

```
$ProcessingStarted = [DateTime]::now
if ($OutputPath) {
   Get-Content -Path "C:\Temp\users-Testing.csv" | Foreach-Object -ThrottleLimit 5 -Parallel {
      $u = Get-EXOMailbox -Identity $_
      $data = Get-EXOMailboxStatistics $u.UserPrincipalName -Archive | Select-Object TotalItemSize, ItemCount
      [PSObject]@{
         DisplayName       = $u.DisplayName
         PrimarySMTP       = $u.PrimarySmtpAddress
         TotalSize         = $data.TotalItemSize
         AutoExpandEnabled = $u.AutoExpandingArchiveEnabled -eq $true
      }
   } | Export-Csv -Path $OutputPath -NoTypeInformation
}
Get-ReadableTimeSince $ProcessingStarted
```

**Everything Parallel Version:** The following code will, in PowerShell 7, theoretically do 5 parallel request for information on users from the server.  It is theoretical due to the fact that I currently cannot recreate esquared's working environment, which prevents me properly testing it.

The code is limited to 5 parallel request, but this can be changed by changing the `-ThrottleLimit` argument of the `Foreach-Object` cmdlet to the desired number.  **NOTE: The server's load should be monitored to verify that it isn't being overloaded with request.**

This first section is the setup of everything we need:

```
#  Either receive or define path where output should be saved.
Param (
   [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
   [string]$OutputPath = 'C:\Temp\Users-ArchiveSize.csv'
)
#Function for converting a [TimeSpan] into human readable time span
function Get-ReadableTimeSpan {
   [CmdletBinding()]
   param (
      [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
      [TimeSpan]$TimeSpan
   )
   [string[]]$TimeList =
   @( $TimeSpan.Days, 'day' ),
   @( $TimeSpan.Hours, 'hour' ),
   @( $TimeSpan.Minutes, 'minute' ),
   @( [float]($TimeSpan.Seconds + $TimeSpan.Milliseconds / 1000), 'second' ) |
   .{ process {
         if ($_[0] -ne 1 -and $_[0] -ne 1.0) { $_[1] += 's' }
         if (($_[0])) { '{0} {1}' -f $_[0], $_[1] }
      } }
   if ($TimeList.Count -eq 0) { $TimeList += '0 seconds' }
   $LastIndex = $TimeList.Count - 1
   if ($LastIndex -ge 2) { $TimeList[$LastIndex] = 'and ' + $TimeList[$LastIndex]; $TimeList -join ', ' }
   else { $TimeList -join ' and ' }
}
#  Open a connection
Connect-ExchangeOnline -UserPrincipalName admin@job.com  -ConnectionUri "https://outlook.office365.com/powershell?email=@yourmailaddress"
#  Get a full list of users and then allocate the same number of cells in $Results
$Users = Get-Content -Path "C:\Temp\users-Testing.csv"
$Results = [PSObject[]]::new($Users.Count)
```

This section does the actual work:

```
#  Capture the amount of time this code runs
$MeasuredTimeSpan = (
   Measure-Command -Expression {
      #  Isolate code from the negative performance effect caused by Measure-Command's Dot Sourcing call of script block
      & {
         $Users | & {   #  This stage packages each user with an index indicating their storage location in $Results.
            begin {
               $Index = 0
            }
            process {
               [PSCustomObject]@{
                  Index  = $Index
                  User   = $Users[$Index]
                  Result = $null
               }
               $Index++
            }
         } | Foreach-Object -ThrottleLimit 5 -Parallel { #  This stage builds and saves each PSObject per each user, but doing multiple in parallel
            #  Collect need information on the user
            $u = Get-EXOMailbox -Identity $_.User
            $data = Get-EXOMailboxStatistics $u.UserPrincipalName -Archive | Select-Object TotalItemSize, ItemCount
            #  Build and save the PSObject containing the needed information on the user
            $_.Result = [PSObject]@{
               DisplayName       = $u.DisplayName
               PrimarySMTP       = $u.PrimarySmtpAddress
               TotalSize         = $data.TotalItemSize
               ItemCount         = $data.ItemCount
               AutoExpandEnabled = $u.AutoExpandingArchiveEnabled -eq $true
            }
            #  Make the PSCustomObject available to the next stage
            $_
         } | & {  #  Save each PSObject in its proper location in $Results
            process {
               $Results[$_.Index] = $_.Result
            }
         }
      }
   }
)
```

And this section outputs the results:

```
#  Write $Results to file in CSV format
if ($OutputPath) {
   $Results | Export-Csv -Path $OutputPath -NoTypeInformation
}
#  Convert the captured [TimeSpan] to human readable time span
Get-ReadableTimeSpan $MeasuredTimeSpan
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this!  The explanations on why you adjusted what you did is great and makes sense.  I'll do some testing and let you know how it works out!  I'm juggling a bunch of projects, so if I don't get back to you today, I'll do my best for tomorrow.  Thanks again!

Also, I'm only using the Measure-Command to test how long it's taking to see what gains I'm getter as I try different approaches to improve the script.  The final script will not have it.  I'll try testing it and time it manually without using it on a smaller number to see if there's any difference in performance.

Comment: I took the previous script, before the parallel processing, and tested it with a batch of 100 mailboxes, also removed the "itemcount" variable as I don't need it anymore and it brought the time down to 5 min for the 100 mailboxes.  I then tested it again, removing the measure-command and it looks like it does affect the performance for the "for" loop because it brought the time down to 3 min, manually timing it on my phone, those are huge time savers.  I'm using PS 7.4.0, the location for modules is in the PS 7 folder, I tried the command in the link and it didn't return any info.

Comment: I'll take a look at the parallel processing and see if I can't incorporate that to help speed it up more.

Comment: @esquared, I've made a few changes to the "Barebones" part of the "conclusion" section (Near bottom of the answer).  I'm leaning towards that code, assuming it is working code, as being the best answer to your question.  There is a "NOTE:" on possibly removing to parts of the code, if you do find either or both are removable, let me know so I can edit the answer.

Comment: the comment must have been deleted, it was saying that there may have been some incompatibility between the module in PS 5.1 and PS 7.3.9 and there was a link to an article to check the location, it wasn't working but it looks like it's since been removed.  You can remove the measure-command, I was using it to time the script to quantify the performance increases, but since it dramatically affects the performance I've removed it and just manually time it now.

Comment: there's no importance to the order of the users, we need to process them all, so it doesn't matter when they get processed, just that they do.  I'll do my best to try and test the parallel processing today.

Comment: If you look at the Barebones section, I've replaced the `Measure-Command` with a simple `$ProcessingStarted = [DateTime]::now`.  This gets the time at just prior to execution of the `Get-Content` command.  Then, after done, the command `Get-ReadableTimeSince $ProcessingStarted` calls a function I've included that immediately calculates `$TimeSpan = [DateTime]::now - $DateTime`, which gets a `[TimeSpan]` that is then used to create a human readable string representing the time that has passed.

Comment: Don't worry about the deleted comments, I was just worried about you using PowerShell 5.1 and having difficult getting started in 7.x.x, was directing you to try to get 7.3.9 instead of 7.4.0, and wait until 7.4.1.  But that is fine.  I wasn't warned explicitly about the problems with 7.4.0, and I expect they are in areas outside of anything we are doing - and 7.4.1 will probably come along soon.

Comment: That is very cool, will test and let you know how it goes, thanks for all your help!

Comment: @esquared, FYI: PowerShell 7.4.1 is now available.

Comment: Excellent, thank you, I'll install that module.  I'm still working on the script, some of my other work projects are taking priority, but I'm hoping to dig deeper into it this week!

Comment: @esquared, that is fine.  No rush.  Just wanted you to know the new PowerShell is out.  Up until now, I've only been experimenting in 7, but think I will now switch to 7.4.1 and use 5.1 only when I need to verify backwards compatibility.

Comment: I added my testing results above but it's not working properly, I'm not sure where the issue is?

Comment: @esquared, the error you are showing is what I get when I try it in PowerShell 5.1. Are you using PowerShell 7.x.x?

Comment: @esquared,  I don't think you want the outer `& {` and matching `}` .  That was only needed with `Measure-Command`

Comment: I removed those and I get the same errors.

Comment: @esquared, what version of PowerShell are you using?

Comment: apologies, I looked and I was running the script in PS5.1 and not PS7.4.1.  I've run it in 7.4.1 and it's working great!  I actually had to modify the script a little because we were accidently creating a false value for "AutoExpandingArchiveEnabled" and I found out that get-mailbox isn't supported in the runstate of the script block.  It took me a min to figure out that I could pull the value from Get-EXOMailbox -PropertySets Archive.  It increased the time a little but I can live with that.  Thank for all your help!!!

Comment: Glad to hear it is working!  Do you know how long it is currently taking to run? I would like to update the answer.

Comment: The first run on the full list, I'll need to have to add a check because I discovered that the list of 18,000 mailboxes are "technically" not all "user" mailboxes even though they're created that way.  Some of the mailboxes are for a products or team but couldn't be, or weren't, set up as shared mailbox.  When the script hit's those mailboxes it stops and errors because the Archive mailbox is not enabled, and then continues, which slows it down a lot.   The total time for that run was 5.5 hours.  I'm hoping the net result of the check vs receiving errors increases its time.

Comment: The end goal of this script will combine 3 scripts. One that pulls the names and formats them to be used in this script.  Once this script finishes, those result will be used in another script to filter the total size of the archive mailbox and based on a size threshold will enable the auto expanding archive feature for those mailboxes.  You might be asking why not just enable that feature at the org level?  Our member firm doesn't "own" O365 and that team refuses to do that because of all the other member firms.  We just need to keep running this monthly to catch new employees.

Comment: Again, thank you, the original script I brought here took over 3 days to run, now it's down to 5.5 hours, that's amazing!!!  It's already gaining interest and others are coming up with other ways to use it to look and change other configurations for large numbers of mailboxes!  I wouldn't be surprised if it made its way to the other member firms as well.

Comment: I'm also looking at a better way to time the script.  I've been playing with different methods from other posts that won't affect the processing time:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38513806/output-the-date-time-in-powershell and 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41660813/measure-execution-time-in-minutes-and-seconds

Comment: @esquared, thank you for the updates!  I'm glad this is working!  A couple of thoughts: First, do you have a network or server expert who has any idea what `ThrottleLimit` is best?  We do not want to overwhelm the server or network with too many request at one time, which is why I used `5` for the initial value.  Second, the only way to time the script is to get `now`, `[DateTime]::now` or `(Get-Date)`, prior to running code and then do the same after running code.  With those 2 values, subtract the before value from the after value to get the timespan.  Do you need a different display?

Comment: Thanks, that's a great tip!  I talked to one of our architect and he said since it's O365, MS has a throttle limit but it's not publicized so I'll have to increment up slowly and see what happens, trial and error for the best time.  As for timeing the script, I was trying to do something very similar to (get-date) and subtracting it but there was a formatting error, I'm going to spend some time on it in the next day or two, I'll let you know my results.

Comment: @esquared, it appears your goal is to identify mailboxes that need the auto-expanding archive feature activated, based on their size thresholds. Do you have data on what percentage of mailboxes that currently have this feature enabled, and is there ever a scenario where it needs to be disabled? If a substantial portion already have it enabled and there's rarely a need for disabling, then maybe the script could log each modified account to the hard drive. Then, in subsequent runs, the script could focus solely on unprocessed accounts, potentially reducing execution time.

Comment: That is the goal of this script, pull all users, filter out who has it enabled and enable those over a specific size threshold.  Once on, the feature cannot be turned off.  It was a good suggestion to remember those users that have it enabled.  Unfortunately, because of employee turnover and we have hundreds, if not thousands, of students coming and going yearly, and the usernames are being recycled. We would eventually run into cases where someone departed and a new hire with the same username as a remembered username with the feature on and get missed.

Comment: Oh!  Never occurred to me you might reuse a username.  Where I'm at, we use the persons initials and a 4 or 5 digit number.  And once you are in the system, the virtual version you is remembered forever.

Answer (score 1):

In PowerShell, when you use `+=` to add an item to an array, it actually creates a new array and copies all items to it.

If you can filter objects earlier in your pipeline, do so. The less data PowerShell has to pass along the pipeline, the faster your script can run.

Here’s a version of your script that uses a generic list instead of an array:

```
Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)] 
    [string]$OutputPath = 'C:\Temp\Users-ArchiveSize.csv'
)

Connect-ExchangeOnline -UserPrincipalName admin@job.com  -ConnectionUri "https://outlook.office365.com/powershell?email=@yourmailaddress"

$Users = Get-Content -Path "C:\Temp\users-Testing.csv"

$result = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[object]

foreach($user in $users) {
    $u = Get-EXOMailbox -Identity $user

    If ($u.AutoExpandingArchiveEnabled -eq $true) {
        $autoArchiveEnabled = "True"
    }
    Else {
        $autoArchiveEnabled = "False"
    }

    $displayName = $u.DisplayName
    $primarySmtpAddress = $u.PrimarySmtpAddress

    $data = Get-EXOMailboxStatistics $u.UserPrincipalName -Archive | select TotalItemSize,ItemCount
    $totalSize = $data.TotalItemSize
    $itemCount = $data.ItemCount

    $result.Add((New-Object psobject -Property @{
        'DisplayName' = $displayName;
        'PrimarySMTP' = $primarySmtpAddress;
        'TotalSize' = $totalSize;
        'ItemCount' = $itemCount;
        'AutoExpandEnabled' = $autoArchiveEnabled;
    }))
}

if ($OutputPath) {
    $result | Export-Csv -Path $OutputPath -NoTypeInformation
}
```